# alternative definition of dual sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm looking for a way to describe the dual of a coherent torsion sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on lets say a variety $X$ over $\mathbf{C}$. Because $Hom(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{O}_X)=0$, I was wondering if there is another way to define a dual sheaf. If  $\mathcal{F}$ is a line bundle, supported e.g. on some reduced divisor $D$ on $X$, then we can still dualise by inverting transition functions. Is there maybe are general way to do this that does not involve taking hom - sections? Maybe via some resolution of $\mathcal{F}$? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction you are probably after is the derived functor $R\operatorname{\cal{Hom}}(\mathcal F, {\mathcal O}_X)$. This can be computed by replacing $\mathcal F$ by a locally free resolution and then dualizing this resolution. It might not be what you are after because it gives you a complex. For example, if $X$ is smooth and you want to dualize the trivial line bundle $\mathcal O_D$ on a smooth divisor $D$, its dual will be $\mathcal O_D(D)[-1]$*, i.e. the dual line bundle, but seen as a complex in degree $1$.

Here's one reason why you might want to use $R\operatorname{\cal{Hom}}$ instead of naively dualizing: there is a restriction map $\mathcal O_X\to \mathcal O_D$, but if you dualize these sheaves seen as a line bundle on $X$ and on $D$, you would get the same sheaves. There is no "dual map" going the opposite way between then duals, because $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal O_D,\mathcal O_X)=0$. There is, however, a dual "map" in $R\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal O_D[-1],\mathcal O_X)$.

*Sasha is completely right . The resolution of $\mathcal O_D$ is
$$
\mathcal O_X(-D)\to \mathcal O_X,
$$
which dualized becomes:
$$
\mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_X(D)
$$
Which is the same resolution from before, tensored with $\mathcal O_X(D)$, i.e. a resolution of $\mathcal O_D(D)$. However, dualizing has sent the complex in degrees $[-1,0]$ to $[0,1]$, so it's resolving $\mathcal O_D(D)[-1]$.

Comment: The derived dual of $\mathcal{O}_D$ is $\mathcal{O}_D(D)[-1]$ (you forgot the normal bundle).

Comment: Thank you so much. In my brain today all varieties are affine space. Really the affine plane.